# Augmenting Image Data on Small Dataset

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I want to train image segmentation model using U-Net with pretrained ResNet34 as encoder. My dataset is really small, i separate it with

- Train data : 57 images
- Validation data : 16 images
- Test data : 8 images

So, with that data, i want to use image augmentation on train data, but should the validation data be augmented too?

Comment: Hello, I think this question has already been answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564146/does-it-make-sense-to-use-data-augmentation-on-the-validation-set-note-this-i) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476748/train-test-validation-splits-and-augmentation). However, segmentation is a nontrivial task, and I feel that your dataset is *very* small. Have you explored few-shot image segmentation literature?

Comment: @Ciodar Hi, thank you for referring that answer. I've watched some youtube videos and read some paper of image segmentation especially that use same dataset as mine, and it also did augmentation. here's one of my references https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0208521620300747

Answer (score 1):

We usually don't touch the validation and test data because modifying them may result in unrealistic performance measurements.

In some cases, people might choose to augment (or in general modify) the validation set, but note that this might even hurt your test performance because the validation and test distributions may diverge and whatever hyper-parameter you optimize for the validation set might not be good for the test set anymore.

Of course, this isn't destined to happen, but the risk associated with modifying your evaluation sets is a non-negligible one.

Comment: so is it okay if the final result of dataset is highly imbalanced? (because augmentation only applied on train data)

Comment: Yes, this is ok. Modifying your test/validation set might result in unrealistic perf. measurements.

Comment: thank you for your answer!